# Update mulitple connection string data sources with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, connection-string, config

So I'm following what seemed like a pretty straight-forward demo on the internet to update the `data-source` attribute on my SQL connection string. However, this line originally threw the error below

```
$doc = (gc $file) -as [xml]
```

> gc : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\LVOAGT.exe.config' because it does not exist.

Since I'm brand new to Powershell I removed the `gc` and the error went away... however now the `$doc` variable is blank. Any idea how to grab a config file and use the method below to just update the `data source` portion of my connection string?

```
#environment variables
$env = "DEV"                       #This will need to be changed from DEV / INT / QUA / PRD
$oldServer = "QUASQ03"          #This will need to be changed from DEV / INT / QUA / PRD

#file and folder variables
$directory = "D:\AMS"
$folders = @("AgentsMonetToDss")

#new database value
$newValue = "$env-AgentResources-AMS-SQL.CORP"

#pull config file and insert new database connection
foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    Write-Host "Updating app.config for $folder" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $dir = Get-ChildItem $directory\$folder -Recurse
    $config = $dir  | where {$_.extension -eq ".config"}

    foreach($file in $config)
    {
        $doc = (gc $file) -as [xml]
        $root = $doc.get_DocumentElement();
        $newCon = $root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString.Replace("data source=$oldServer\sql08a", "data source=$newValue\sql08a")
        $root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString = $newCon
        $doc.Save($file)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of what's contained in the first iteration of the inner `foreach` loop in the `$file` variable. The information in the pop up is accurate (filename, directory)

[image]

**SECOND EDIT**

So the following code below will update the connection string. However this line gives the error below.

```
$root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString = $newCon
```

> The property 'connectionString' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

```
    $doc = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName)
    $root = $doc.get_DocumentElement();
    [string]$newCon = $root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString.Replace($oldServer, $newValue)
    $root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString = $newCon
    $doc.Save($file.FullName)
```

**THIRD EDIT**

The error `'connectionString' cannot be found on this object` appears to be because we have multiple connection strings in the `<connectionStrings>` node. If I remove one of the connection strings from the config then the script runs fine. So I guess the question is how do I update MULTIPLE connection strings using powershell? The issue seems to be these lines below

```
$newCon = $root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString.Replace($oldServer, $newValue)
$root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString = $newCon
```

The first line will scour both connection strings and replace the value as is requested to do. However, since I have simply a long string in `$newCon` and I'm attempting to add to the `connectionString` property of `$root` there's a clash.

Comment: It's not supposed to be pulling from `Windows\system32`. Updated the post.

Comment: I already call `Get-ChildItem` on `$directory\$folder`. That part is doing what it's meant to do (I can see all the files from that directory).

Comment: @user2864740 updated the post with information from debugging session

Comment: I believe it should be `(gc $file.FullName)`.

Comment: Thanks, that got me past the original error. New error now... updated the post.

Comment: try this for the replace process. `Replace($("data source=$oldServer\sql08a"), $("data source=$newValue\sql08a"))`

Comment: I was able to get past the `replace` issue by changing the line to this: `$newCon = $root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString.Replace($oldServer, $newValue)`, however now I'm still stuck with the `'connectionString' cannot be found ` error.....

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but it worked...

I eventually had to store the entire connection string in a variable and run a `-contains` check against the `connectionString` property. Will leave this post open for awhile in case anyone has a much efficient solution.

```
#generated config connection strings
Write-Host "Updating config ConnectionString nodes" -ForegroundColor Green
foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    Write-Host "Updating config for $folder" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $dir = Get-ChildItem $directory\$folder -Recurse 
    $config = $dir  | where {$_.extension -eq ".config"}

    foreach($file in $config)
    {       
        $doc = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName) 
        $doc.configuration.connectionStrings.add |%{
            if($_.connectionString.ToLower() -contains $oldGenConn.ToLower()){
                $_.connectionString = $newGenConn
            }            
        }
        $doc.Save($file.FullName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your connection string in your .exe.config files are as follows:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnectionExternal" connectionString="DbConnectionExternal" />
    <add name="DbConnectionSecurity" connectionString="DbConnectionSecurity" />
    <add name="ErrorDb" connectionString="ErrorDb" />
    <add name="OracleConnection" connectionString="OracleConnection" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

After executing the following script file, this connection string inside all the .exe.config files which exists inside your root folder of the given path will be updated to:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnectionExternal" connectionString="A" />
    <add name="DbConnectionSecurity" connectionString="B" />
    <add name="ErrorDb" connectionString="C" />
    <add name="OracleConnection" connectionString="D" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Script file:

```
get-childitem "Include the file path of your root folder" -recurse | where {$_.Name -match ".exe.config"} | % {
         $appConfigFile = $_.FullName
    $appConfig = New-Object XML
    $appConfig.Load($appConfigFile)
    foreach($connectionString in $appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add){
            if($connectionString.name -eq 'DbConnectionExternal'){
        $connectionString.connectionString = 'A'
        }
            elseif($connectionString.name -eq 'DbConnectionSecurity'){
        $connectionString.connectionString = 'B'
        }
            elseif($connectionString.name -eq 'ErrorDb'){
        $connectionString.connectionString = 'C'
        }
            elseif($connectionString.name -eq 'OracleConnection'){
        $connectionString.connectionString = 'D'
        }
    }
    $appConfig.Save($appConfigFile)
    }
```

It works perfectly and this script will be very useful when you deploy your application in to a server. You do not need to update each and every config file one by one.